# Resource is removed from the APIGateway after re-deployment CloudFormation stack without template changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have created an `APIGateway, APIGateway::Resource and APIGateway::Method` in the template. When I deployed the stack for the first time, the Resource and Method were created without problems, but after repeated deployment I don’t see them in the APIGateway. There is no record of their deletion in the stack event logs, but when I look at drifts between stack and template, I see that resource and method were deleted.

My template:

```
Resources:

    MyApiGateway:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
        Properties:
            Name: !Sub 'MyApi'
            StageName: prod

    MyMethod:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
        DependsOn: MyResource
        Properties:
            AuthorizationType: NONE
            HttpMethod: GET
            ...
            ResourceId: !Ref MyResource
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApiGateway

    MyResource:
        Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
        DependsOn: MyApiGateway
        Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApiGateway
            ParentId: !GetAtt
                - MyApiGateway
                - RootResourceId
            PathPart: some_path
```

The problem is solved this way: remove these resources from template, update stack, restore resources in template and update stack again. But deleting and restoring resources every time is not the best solution.